# Why doesn't Ping.Send work in a for-loop?

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, asynchronous, ping

The contents inside the for-loop works fine on its own, but currently after the loop runs, the PingTimes -list is always empty. Whats going on here? Pretty new to C# here.

```
        private void PingTest()
    {
        List<long> PingTimes = new List<long>();
        Ping PingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

        options.DontFragment = true;

        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;


        for (int i = 1; i >= TimesToPing; i++)
        { 
            PingReply reply = PingSender.Send(PingAddress, timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                PingTimes.Add(reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ping test failed due to an unknown reason.");
                break;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Pinged Address: " + PingAddress + "\nAverage Ping: " + PingTimes.Average().ToString() + "ms");
    }
```

Comment: Master in computer science should really know how to use a _debugger_

Answer (score 4):

Your for loop condition is inverted, and so the loop will never run. :)

Comment: this is so humiliating.

Comment: @Ricochet Just a tip, and I'm not saying this to be a dick, but when a loop isn't behaving, put a print inside the loop to ensure that the loop itself is running as you expect.